# Show that $T-iI$ is invertible when $T$ is self-adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T$ be a self adjoint operator on a finite dimensional inner product space $V$.    Then $ \| T(x)\pm ix \|^2=\| T(x) \|^2+\| x\|^2$ for all $x \in V$.   Deduce that $T-iI$ is inverible.

Since $\| T(x)\pm ix \|=0$ iff $\| T(x)\|=0$ and $\| x \|=0$ and it means $N(T)=0$ and it is one-to-one.   Since $V$ is finite dimensional, $T$ is onto. Thus $T$ is invertible.    Hence, $T-iI$  is invertible.

Is this proof complete?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Note that this is also true on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, as $T$ self-adjoint has a real spectrum, which therefore never contains $i$.

Comment: @julien In infinite-dimensional space $T$ is injective but not necessary invertible. Isn't it?

Comment: @julien Sorry but from your last comment "this is also true on an infinite...." can I understand that $T-iI$ is also invertible? I'm not sure for this result.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane On an infinite Hilbert space, $T+iI$ will be bounded below, so the image is closed. To show the operator is invertible, we only need to show the orthogonal complement of the image is trivial. If $\langle Tx+ix,z\rangle=0$ for all $x$, you get $\langle x,Tz-iz\rangle$ for all $x$, hence $Tz-iz=0$. By the same argument as before, conclude $z=0$.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane I did not say the argument applied verbatim. On any Hilbert space, if $T$ is (bounded) self-adjoint, then $T-\lambda  Id$ is invertible (i.e. $\lambda \not\in \sigma(T)$) for any $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$. That's equivalent to the assertion: $\sigma(T)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. The key point is below boundedness, as mentioned by Harald.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Thanks very much.

Comment: @julien Ok now I see thanks.

Comment: @RudevanNistelrooy Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct. Note that this is also true on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, as $T$ self-adjoint [has a real spectrum](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1035634/147263), which therefore never contains $i$. -- [1015](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408490/show-that-t-ii-is-invertible#comment874290_408490)

In an infinite-dimensional space, being bounded from below does not imply invertibility in general. So, an additional argument is needed for this case. --  [Sami Ben Romdhane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408490/show-that-t-ii-is-invertible/1035894#comment874295_408490)

Since $T+iI$ is bounded below, its image is closed. To show the operator is invertible, we only need to show the orthogonal complement of the image is trivial. If $\langle Tx+ix,z\rangle=0$ for all $x$, you get $\langle x,Tz-iz\rangle$ for all $x$, hence $Tz-iz=0$. By the same argument as before, conclude $z=0$. -- [Harald Hanche-Olsen](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408490/show-that-t-ii-is-invertible#comment874310_408490)

---

<sup>Comments edited to improve the flow.</sup>