# Spectrum of a Self-Adjoint Operator is Real

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Preparing for an exam in functional analysis, I'm trying to show that for a self-adjoint operator $A$, $\sigma(A) \subset \mathbb{R}$. I came across the following proof in the book (or rather, lecture notes) we're using for the course. The proof is even stronger, giving bounds for the spectrum. However, I have issue with the proof. Here is the proof:

Let $m = \inf_{||x||=1}{\langle Ax, x \rangle}$ and $M= \sup_{||x|=1}{\langle Ax, x \rangle}$. Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} \backslash [m,M]$. Define $d = \mathrm{dist}(\lambda, [m,M])$. By the Cauchy Schwarz inequality we have $||(A- \lambda I)x|| \ge |\langle (A- \lambda I)x, x \rangle| =|\langle Ax, x \rangle - \lambda| \ge d$. Thus $||A-\lambda I||$ is bounded below and is hence invertible.

My problem wiht this proof is 2-fold. First, this seems to assume that (if $||x||=1$, then) $\langle Ax,x \rangle \in \mathbb{R}$. Further, I don't see how this uses the fact that $A$ is self-adjoint! If I had to guess, $A$ self-adjoint implies that $\langle Ax,x \rangle \in \mathbb{R}$ (when $||x|| = 1$), but I don't seem to be able to figure out how to make that connection.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Typographical comment: `$\|x\|$` looks better than `$||x||$`. Compare $\|x\|$ and $||x||$.

Comment: Thanks. I have a command (\norm{}) that I got from someone else, and couldn't actually remember what the long-hand for it was offhand

Answer (score 3):

Self-adjointness is used   to show that $\langle Ax,x\rangle$ is always real. Recall that $\langle u,v\rangle = \overline{\langle v,u\rangle} $ and use the definition of self-adjointness:
$$
\langle Ax,x\rangle=\langle x,Ax\rangle = \overline{\langle Ax,x\rangle}
$$

The boundedness of $A$ implies that the set $\{\langle Ax,x\rangle:\|x\|=1\}$ is bounded. So, it's a bounded subset of $\mathbb R$. Now $m$ and $M$ make sense and the proof goes as before.

By the way, there is a gap in *is bounded below and is hence invertible*: for example, the shift operator $(x_1,x_2,\dots)\mapsto (0,x_1,x_2,\dots)$ is bounded from below but is not invertible. This is another place where self-adjointness will be invoked: re-read the proof to see what goes on there.

---

If you don't need bounds for the spectrum, you could simplify the proof by dropping $M$ and $m$. Since the modulus of a complex number is at least the modulus of its imaginary part,
$$
\|(A- \lambda I)x\| \ge |\langle (A- \lambda I)x, x \rangle| =|\langle Ax, x \rangle - \lambda| \ge |\operatorname{Im} \lambda|
$$

Comment: Self adjointness is also used to conclude from the "bounded below" property (which is equivalent to $A-\lambda$ being injective with closed range) to $A-\lambda$ being invertible (which adds surjectivity to the preceding properties), isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but $\Vert Ax \Vert \geq \Vert x \Vert$ does not imply in general that $A$ is invertible, take $A x = (x_1,0,x_2,0,x_3,\dots)$ on $\ell^2$.

Comment: Thanks; I edited the answer.

Comment: Hmm... These lecture notes do have something about for A self-adjoint, invertible if and only if bounded below... He only has a brief proof, though. Guess I'll have to try and dissect it

Comment: @Mike [This comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408490/show-that-t-ii-is-invertible#comment874310_408490) might help.

Comment: It didn't really, but I think I understand it now anyway

Comment: Not to de-rail my own question, but I actually have a slightly new question: For your alternative (when I don't need $m$ and $M$), does that work generally if I don't assume $\|x\| =1$? I have another problem to prove that fact for general $x$, and that's a pretty easy proof if so. But I'm concerned because I think a $\|x\|^2$ would show up, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Mike  I am still assuming $\|x\|=1$ there. When proving an upper or lower bound on a linear operator, it's pretty common to make this assumption. Otherwise the argument is the same, but with a few factors of $\|x\|$ thrown in.

Comment: Well, my thinking is where you have $|\langle Ax, x \rangle - \lambda|$, if $\|x\| \neq 1$ then we would get $|\langle Ax, x \rangle - \lambda\|x\|^2|$, right? How do I pull out a $\|x\|$?

Comment: @Mike It would be $$\|(A- \lambda I)x\| \ge |\langle (A- \lambda I)x, x \rangle|/\|x\| =|\langle Ax, x \rangle - \lambda \|x\|^2|/\|x\| \ge |\operatorname{Im} \lambda|\|x\|^2/\|x\| $$

Comment: @Mike When working with linear operators, it is usual to use their homogeneity. Every nonzero vector $x$ can be written as $x=ty$ with $\|y\|=1$, just by letting $t=\|x\|$ and $y=x/t$. With this substitution, the inequality $\|(A-\lambda I)x\| \ge |\mathrm{Im} \ \lambda| \|x\|$ that you want becomes $\|(A-\lambda I)y\| \ge |\mathrm{Im} \ \lambda|$.

Comment: Wait, I see it now. For some reason I couldn't see how it was working in the longer version before, but now I see it. I knew you generally assume $\|x\| = 1$, but for some reason I was having problems with it before because I couldn't see how something worked. But now I do. Thanks for all the help.